# TD visible issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, visible

I have browsed the different cases already answered about the topic but did not find the one answering my question:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstView_phoneUsersExtensionsFound" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lstView_phoneUsersExtensionsFound_ItemDataBound">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table id="tbl1" runat="server" class="bordered">
      <tr id="tr1" runat="server">
        <th id="th1" runat="server" visible='<%# selectOptionVisible %>' >Select</th>
        <th id="th1" runat="server">UserID</th>
        <th id="th2" runat="server">Firstname</th>
        <th id="th3" runat="server">Lastname</th>
      </tr>
        <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server">  
      </tr>            
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
       <td runat="server" visible='<%# selectOptionVisible %>' >
         <input type="radio" name="rdbutton_userSelection" value='<%# Eval("uuid") %>' />
         <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdfield_userID" Value='<%# Eval("uuid")%>' />
       </td>
       <td><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Users/DisplayUserDetails.aspx?selectedCCMUserID={0}&uuid={1}",Eval("userID"),Eval("uuid"))%>'><%# Eval("userID")%></asp:HyperLink></td>
       <td><%# Eval("firstname")%></td>
       <td><%# Eval("lastname")%></td>
     </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
 <EmptyDataTemplate></EmptyDataTemplate></asp:ListView>
```

The repeater layouttemplate header does not take into account the visible value but the different items work well and hide the cell when needed.
I would like to keep using an aspx function and not go through javascript or CSS if possible.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the below code does the trick but I am sure there should be a better way.

```
  protected void lstView_phoneUsersExtensionsFound_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlTableCell th_selectColumn = (HtmlTableCell)lstView_phoneUsersExtensionsFound.FindControl("th1");
    th_selectColumn.Visible = selectOptionVisible;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<th id="th1" runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("selectOptionVisible") %>'>
```

The problem was in visible='<%# **selectOptionVisible** %>'

Instead I changed it to visible='<%# **Eval("selectOptionVisible")** %>'

Make sure that your data source contains a column as **selectOptionVisible**

### Note

To hide the column header i.e <th>,

1. Load the "selectOptionVisible to a variable in the code behind while page loading.
2. Instead of '<%# Eval("selectOptionVisible") %>'

   now you can use '<%# **selectOptionVisibleVariable** %>'.
3. Set value for selectOptionVisibleVariable before loading data to ListView.

Comment: Hi, when doing so, it does not like the structure: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRowCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Another strange thing is that I cannot (unknown variable) access the table property using the ID like th1.visible = "true"

Comment: Dear Salim, your problem is in showing the values or showing some values based on the visibility criteria. Because when I checked, it is coming properly.

Comment: Hi, I want to hide the first column according to the value of the selectOptionVisible (true, false). The instructions visible='<%# selectOptionVisible %>' are the same but seems to only be applied to the rows not the header of the table.

Comment: Hi, I tested this before posting, but still no effect. The first column head (called "select") still apears :-(

Comment: Its because Eval("selectOptionVisible") will not carry any value while populating <LayoutTemplate>. It will start loading values on <ItemTemplate>. So you can follow the steps I add in the answer.

Comment: Ok, that works. Strange thing is that I tested it before. I work with code coming from a user control so it might be that I changed something since I lasted tested. Thanks for your appreciated answers.

Comment: Ok, now I found why is disregarded this option. It only works well on the lineitem of my listview but strangely enough, the same code does not work in the header section (LayoutTemplate). Anyway...